# Extraer <span class="down">3,153.20</span>

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, nodejs

Necesito extraer el texto de ese span, solo el valor, alguna forma? tengo toda la página en tipo texto, solo necesito es parte.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>prueba</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style>
#content-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:black;
    margin:0px 600px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top: 160px;
    left: 90px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

                <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                    <source id="source-video" src="" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                
    
                <div id="contenido">
                <div id="content-text"></div>
          
        <script>
            $(function(){
            $.ajax({url: "https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators", success: function(result){
            $("#content-text").text(result);
            }});
            });
        </script>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>SemanaIndicators</title>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Amcharts/serial.js"></script>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Amcharts/amstock.js"></script>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Amcharts/themes/light.js"></script>
 <script src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Amcharts/lang/es.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/Semana/SemanaIndicators/app.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/widgetsdataifx/Content/themes/Semana/SemanaIndicators/app.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var redirect = "http://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/widgetsdataifx/Scripts/avisolegal.html";
 if(document.referrer.indexOf("semana") == -1 && document.referrer.indexOf("dinero") == -1 && document.referrer.indexOf("finanzaspersonales") == -1 && document.referrer.indexOf("widgetsdataifx") == -1)
 {if (top.location != self.location && document.referrer != ""){
 var s = 'http://137.135.67.207:8087/RegistroWidgets/Registro.ashx?w='+self.location+'&p='+document.referrer;
 $(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({ data: { 'x':'dataifx'},type:'GET',url:s,cache:false,success: function(response) { self.location = redirect;},error: function(response) { self.location = redirect;}});}); }}
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="page">
 <table class="content">
 <tbody>
 <tr class="item-row" data-item="TRM">
 <td class="item-name">D&#243;lar (TRM)</td>
 <td class="item-value">

 <span class="down">3,153.20</span>
 </td>
 <td class="item-variation">-0.48%</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Copia el `result` como texto y no como foto.

Comment: Pero es muy largo @alanfcm

Comment: Copia solo una parte que contenga el span que quieres.

Comment: Listo. @alanfcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo simplemente con `$(".down").text()` asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>prueba</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#content-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:black;
    margin:0px 100px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top: 160px;
    left: 90px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

                <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                    <source id="source-video" src="" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                        
                <div id="contenido">
                <div id="content-text"></div>
          
        <script>
            $(function(){
            var result = '<table class="content"><tbody><tr class="item-row" data-item="TRM"><td class="item-name">D&#243;lar (TRM)</td><td class="item-value"><span class="down">3,153.20</span></td><td class="item-variation">-0.48%</td></tr></tbody></table>';
            $("#content-text").html(result);
            console.log($(".down").text());
            });
        </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, no se puede hacer pero no tipo `html` si no tipo `text`? y como lo puedo mostrar que no sea en consola así `$(".down").text();` ? @alanfcm

Comment: De poder se puede pero es mas dificil.  Lo que puedes hacer es agregar el html, sacar el valor y luego ya sea resetear el html o hacerlo invisible.  El valor lo puedes guardar en una variable y desplegarlo donde quieras.

Comment: Se puede usar expresiones regulares para obtener un texto que cumpla con un patron definidlo, por ejemplo estar dentro de un span con una clase, seria un poco mas optimo que cargar todo el DOM.

Comment: No se como hacer para que `console.log($(".down").text());` salga en el `content-text` la verdad. @alanfcm

Comment: `$("#content-text").html($(".down").text());`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar expresiones regulares:

```
\<span[\s]*class[\s]*=[\s]*"down"[\s]*>[\s]*(.*)</span>\
```

> Incluyo algunos espacios `[\s]*` para no ser tan estrictos con la estructura
>   del span

Puedes probar el ejemplo que hice: (*Guarde un html de ejemplo de tu respuesta en un text area para poder probar*)

```js
function extraerValor() {
    var data = document.querySelector("#data").value;
    
    
    var res = data.match(/\<span[\s]*class[\s]*=[\s]*\"down\"[\s]*\>[\s]*(.*)\<\/span\>/); 
    
    var result = document.querySelector("#result");
    result.value = res[1];
    
}
```

```html
Respuesta de un html de ejemplo <br/><textarea id="data"> <html> <body><span class="down">3,153.20</span> </body>  </html> </textarea>

<br/><br/>


<a href="javascript:extraerValor()"> Extraer </a><input id="result"/>
```